# Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings Change JDK location in Android Studio And JDK can't found anywhere

Tags: java, android

I opened my Android Studio and it shows me error "Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings
Change JDK location."

And then when i clicked on "Change JDK Location."
It shows me that instead of jdk it shows me jre but jdk can not be found anywhere[This is the Screeshot of the jre showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JWmC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to
File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle

Here Select the Gradle JDK required by your project, Rebuild your project it should work fine[menu sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FN73.png)